# How to remove file extension from nginx location proxy pass path?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I like to pass both `/foo/bar` and `/foo/bar.png` (or `.jpg` etc.) to `/foo/bar`. My attempt on that doesn't work for some reason:

```
location ~ ^(/foo/bar)(\.(jpe?g|png|svg))?$ {
    proxy_pass http://upstream-server$1;
    proxy_...
}
```

Could someone tell me, what were wrong with the regular expression or other parts of the config? Thank you!

Comment: You mean you want to capture `/foo/bar` or `/foo/bar.xxxx` ? It's probably you are not using scape characters. Check this demo out. https://regex101.com/r/IvR9ii/1

Comment: How can I apply this to `nginx` without use of the pcre module?